# Calling Virtual methods during construction and destruction

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

Calling Virtual methods during construction and destruction causes a compiler error? I heard that it is a dangerous thing to do.

I know that if I have a `Class Base` that defines a virtual method `foo()`, the resolution of `foo()` is **dynamic** in all subclasses of `Base`. So if the subclass `Derived` overrides `foo()` then `Derived::foo()` is called. So why calling *virtual methods* during construction/destruction confuses the compiler?

What is the difference between calling them from the constructor, and outside it?

Comment: If not a compiler error, how my program will react to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

During construction of `Base()`, the derived class hasn't been initialized yet, and doesn't really exist yet. When you call a virtual method, your call will go to `Base::foo()`. This isn't necessarily wrong, but is often unexpected, hence the general prohibition against it.

Similarly during destruction, Derived is destroyed before `~Base()` is called, so again virtual method calls will go to `Base::foo()`, which is again often unexpected.

Answer (score 5):

Try running this example:

```
struct base {
   virtual int f() const { return 0; }
   base() { std::cout << f() << "\n"; }
   ~base() { std::cout << f() << "\n"; }
};
struct derived : base {
   const int value;
   derived(int v) : value(v) {}
   virtual int f() const { return value; }
};
derived d(100);       // What should this print?
```

The problem is that when the constructor of the base type is running the type of the object is still `base`, and not `derived`. Dispatch will not hit the *final-overrider* (from the point of view of the user, that has only created a `derived` object). The same happens in destruction.

Comment: I don't think that would compile, since `base` doesn't have a `value` member.  Did you mean for `base` to print the result of `f()`?  Unrelated: This answer doesn't explain _why_ this behavior exists.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Fixed the code. The answer is not completely explicit, but it does say what the issue is: the derived type is not yet constructed, the type is still `base` and the example above can have surprising effects (i.e. `f()` not calling `derived::f`) I am not sure what else needs to be spelled out

Comment: My apologies, I guess I failed to read the paragraph or something.  Not sure what I did.